# I want to change number between A and B to 1, but I don't know how many digits are there in between A and B.EG:(A11B,A2B).(with sed)

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I want to change number between A and B to 1, but I don't know how many digits are there in between A and B.EG:(A11B,A2B). I tried following but it is  limited to single digit. 
sed  "s/A[0-9]B/A1B/" demo

Comment: The duplicate covers a more complex case but really, any introduction to regular expressions will tell you how to repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
sed 's/A[0-9]\+B/A1B/' file
```

The pattern which you used looks for one number. By putting `+`, we are looking for one or more numbers.

Comment: Its working. Thanks